# visualization for output of topic modelling

Tags: python-3.x, topic-modeling, nmf

For topic modelling I use the method called nmf(Non-negative matrix factorisation). Now, I want to visualise it.So, can someone tell me visualisation techniques for topic modelling.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend topicwizard https://github.com/x-tabdeveloping/topic-wizard
(full disclosure: it was written by me)

It's a highly interactive dashboard for visualizing topic models, where you can also name topics and see relations between topics, documents and words.

Here are some example screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check LDAvis if you're using R; pyLDAvis if Python. It was developed for LDA. But I guess it also works for NMF, by treating one matrix as topic_word_matrix and the other as topic proportion in each document.

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bmabey/pyLDAvis/blob/master/notebooks/pyLDAvis_overview.ipynb

Comment: Nope, pyLDAvis does not support NMF